# how to override backpress to not kill activity?

Tags: android

I would like to display some images when the application is opened for the first time. Or if its being reopened. I don't want the application to be killed when the user presses the back button, to go to the home screen. But instead keep it alive but still return to the home screen.

Comment: So what's the difference between clicking the back press button and the home button on devices????

Comment: coder, it helps to read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Andro_Selva said, the back button finishes your activity; it doesn't kill the app.

If you want to accomplish something similar to pressing the home button (so your app is hidden, but the activity is still alive), you can do something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

It's a little different than pressing the home key, because it will only take you to last app you were in when you launched this app.  So it won't necessarily take you back to the launcher. But this behavior will be closer to what the user expects when pressing back.

You may also want to put this in the Manifest under your root Activity :

```
android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
```

This will prevent Android's default behavior of finishing all your Activities if they have been idle for about half an hour.

Answer (score 2):

add this to your activity

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    //finish(); this is what would normally happen
}
```

This way you have the full control on the back key. As for the home key, you better not do anything to it. otherwise it could be a big problem if something goes wrong with your app, and the user wont be able to get out of it. Also if you look at how android works, when a home key is pressed, the app isn't killed, just paused, unless the system decides there is not enough memory to keep your app, in which case it will shut down.

Answer (score 0):

```
how to override backpress to not kill activity?
```

I believe that you have not understood certain things here. When you press your back button it doesn't mean that you are killing your app. It means that you are finishing your activity and  which also means that your app is running in the background. If you want to kill your activity you have to do one of these,

1. by calling `System.exit(0);`
2. Or by

   ```
      int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
      android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
   ```
3. Or by manually getting into settings->manage applications->select your app->click on force stop

When you press your **home key** it means that your activity is paused or something like freezed and when you get to your app again, you can see your app resumed from where you left your app.