# Jetpack Compose: Bottom bar navigation not responding after deep-linking

Tags: deep-linking, android-jetpack-compose, android-architecture-navigation

I have setup a bottom bar in my new Jetpack Compose app with 2 destinations. I have tried to follow the samples from Google.

So for example it looks something like this:

```
@Composable
fun MyBottomBar(navController: NavHostController) {
    val items = listOf(
        BottomNavigationScreen.ScreenA,
        BottomNavigationScreen.ScreenB
    )
    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination

    BottomNavigation {
        items.forEach { screen ->
            BottomNavigationItem(
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate(screen.route) {
                        popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id) {
                            saveState = true
                        }

                        launchSingleTop = true
                        restoreState = true

                    }
                },
                selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == screen.route } == true,
                icon = { Icon(imageVector = screen.icon, contentDescription = null) },
                label = { Text(stringResource(screen.label)) }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This all works fine and I'm able to navigate between the two destinations. However, I also have a deep-link to `ScreenB`. Once this has been invoked, pressing the `ScreenA` button seems to do nothing (If I add logging I can see that currentDestination is being repeatedly set to `ScreenB`) but pressing back returns to the startDestination of `ScreenA`.

My workaround at the moment is to remove the `restoreState = true` line from the sample code.

My suspicion is that something about the deep-link is being persisted and although it tries to go to ScreenA the navigation component says that it's got a deep-link pointing to ScreenB so it just goes there. I've tried resetting the activity intent so that it has no flags and no data in the intent, I've even tried changing the intent action type but all to no avail.

I am using Compose 1.0.0-rc02 and Compose Navigation 2.4.0-alpha04.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Nope. I'm now using Compose 1.0.0 and Compose Navigation 2.4.0-alpha08 but the issue still persists. I am having to carry on without the save/restore state

Comment: This behavior drives me crazy :P After some tests, I found something really weird which I can reproduce easily. After the deeplink call, my "Screen A" menu point becomes "Screen B". I mean, I observe the 'navController.currentBackStackEntryFlow' and it returns the good value for others menu point (in my case I have 4), but the main menu point is "broken" and acts like second menu point.

Comment: Definitely sounds like a bug then - not incorrect usage. I'll have a look at the back stack entries myself before and after the deeplink. Does your bottom bar start working normally after you press back?

Comment: Yes, the backstack works normally after that.

Comment: @RémyLavergne It seems to be fixed in 2.4.0-beta02

Comment: Good news! Thank you, I will try that quickly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's finally fixed in the 2.4.0-beta02 release; so it was a bug after all.

I was able to add the saveState and restoreState commands back into my BottomBar (as per the documentation) and following a deep-link I was now still able to click the initial destination.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I am using 2.6.0-alpha04 and am having the same issue.. doesn't work with 2.5.3 too.

Comment: it's 2024 and I don't see it fixed

Comment: @user924, same, tried different compose and compose navigation version

Answer (score 3):

I know you got this code from the official documentation, but I don't think it works well for bottom navigation. It keeps the elements in the navigation stack, so pressing the back button from `ScreenB` will take you back to `ScreenA`, which does not seem to me to be the right behavior in this case.

That's why it's better to remove all elements from the stack, so that only one of the tabs is always left. And with `saveState` you won't lose state anyway. This can be done as follows:

```kotlin
fun NavHostController.navigateBottomNavigationScreen(screen: BottomNavigationScreen) = navigate(screen.route) {
    val navigationRoutes = BottomNavigationScreen.values()
        .map(BottomNavigationScreen::route)
    val firstBottomBarDestination = backQueue
        .firstOrNull { navigationRoutes.contains(it.destination.route) }
        ?.destination
    if (firstBottomBarDestination != null) {
        popUpTo(firstBottomBarDestination.id) {
            inclusive = true
            saveState = true
        }
    }
    launchSingleTop = true
    restoreState = true
}
```

And use it like this:

```kotlin
BottomNavigationItem(
    onClick = {
        navController.navigateBottomNavigationScreen(screen)
    },
    selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.route == screen.route } == true,
    icon = { Icon(imageVector = screen.icon, contentDescription = null) },
    label = { Text(screen.label) }
)
```

For the same reasons, I wouldn't use deep link navigation in this case. Instead, you process them manually. You can use a view model to not re-process deep link if you leave bottom navigation view and come back:

```kotlin
class DeepLinkProcessingViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private var deepLinkProcessed = false

    fun processDeepLinkIfAvailable(context: Context): String? {
        if (!deepLinkProcessed) {
            val activity = context.findActivity()
            val intentData = activity?.intent?.data?.toString()

            deepLinkProcessed = true
            return intentData
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

And using this view model you can calculate start destination like this:

```kotlin
val context = LocalContext.current
val deepLinkProcessingViewModel = viewModel<DeepLinkProcessingViewModel>()
val startDestination = rememberSaveable(context) {
    val deepLink = deepLinkProcessingViewModel.processDeepLinkIfAvailable(context)
    if (deepLink == "example://playground") {
        // deep link handled
        BottomNavigationScreen.ScreenB.route
    } else {
        // default start destination
        BottomNavigationScreen.ScreenA.route
    }
}
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = startDestination) {
    ...
}
```

Or, if you have several navigation elements in front of the bottom navigation and you don't want to lose them with a deep link, you can do it as follows:

```kotlin
val navController = rememberNavController()
val context = LocalContext.current
val deepLinkProcessingViewModel = viewModel<DeepLinkProcessingViewModel>()
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    val deepLink = deepLinkProcessingViewModel.processDeepLinkIfAvailable(context) ?: return@LaunchedEffect
    if (deepLink == "example://playground") {
        navController.navigateBottomNavigationScreen(BottomNavigationScreen.ScreenB)
    }
}
NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = BottomNavigationScreen.ScreenA.route
) {
```

`findActivity`:

```kotlin
fun Context.findActivity(): Activity? = when (this) {
    is Activity -> this
    is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.findActivity()
    else -> null
}
```

Comment: Whilst this does appear to solve the issue after a deep-link (even without doing the hand-rolled deep-link handling that you suggested) it looks like it's adding a lot more elements to the backstack. So rather than having maximum 1 instance of screen B I can end up with lots of them at various places.

Comment: @BarryIrvine Made a mistake when refactoring at the last moment and haven't checked it=) check out updated variant of `navigateBottomNavigationScreen`

Comment: That's better in that all screens are effectively top-level and all exit the app if you press back. I have a problem with my first tab but that's based on my implementation anyway. This is because for ScreenA I have start destination = ComposableZ. But ComposableZ has a launched effect that can launch ComposableY in certain conditions. In any case, your new solution breaks after the deep-link, although presumably your hand-rolled solution fixes it. Perhaps I'll just hope the fix is in the next build of compose navigation. Hopefully there's one tomorrow.

Comment: @BarryIrvine I'm not sure if this can be considered a bug, so it may not be fixed. Navigating from deeplink is equivalent to calling `navigate`, and I doubt it will be possible to specify `popUpTo`. I think specifying `startDestination` manually should solve this problem.  Could you describe your problem with my solution more clearly? If you need to go from `ComposableZ`, you can use the same `navigateBottomNavigationScreen` method for that (if it has to go to one of the bottom navigation routes).

Comment: But surely once a deeplink has been handled then going back to the start destination should not continually try to handle the deeplink again (which is what I believe is happening)

Comment: @BarryIrvine I've updated my answer with storing `deepLinkProcessed` inside a view model to prevent handling it for the second time.

Comment: @PhilDukhov as per this solution when I navigate from Graph1 Screen2 to Graph2 Screen2 (Nested navigation) and press back button, app gets killed.
Can you provide a solution where If I press a back button from Graph2 NestedScreen or If I press GraphA on Bottom Tab this should retain previous state of GraphA.

Comment: @PhilDukhov as per your implementation, can you tell if we navigate from graphA screen 2 to graphB screen 2 (nested navigation), on back press or tab switch how will you retain graphA screen 2 state ?

Comment: @ParveenSharma you can't save state inside `remember` when switching back and force, because the screen is removed from the view tree. But with `saveState = true` and `restoreState = true` your view models are gonna be saved, so you need to store all the data there.

Comment: @ParveenSharma as to back button, it's default behaviour, which can be overriden as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6977978/3585796). [Here](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/6e4409126c619d06e422f9bd4c33fde0) is how you can do it in compose

Comment: `Cannot access 'backQueue': it is invisible (private in a supertype) in 'NavHostController'`

Comment: I replaced it with `currentBackStack.value`, but it works different now, when I press the back button from not start destination it closes the app instead of switching first to start destination screen

Comment: also I still can't navigate to start destination after deeplink with this code but with `currentBackStack.value`

Comment: I guess, yeah, it's better to handle deep link manually and clear the data then ` intent?.setData(null)` or some flag as you mentioned. In this case we can keep using Google implementation of `navigateTopLevelScreen`

Answer (score 1):

Adding some clarifications to the answer giving by Barry Irvine.

They actually fixed it in Navigation 2.4.0-beta02, but that requires not only to update your dependencies, but also do some changes in your code.

In my case, I have 3 destinations A, B, C, where each destination could be navigated through a bottom navigation.
A and C were simple destinations, and B was a sub graph with two destinations, where 1 of the destinations supported deep link.

If you follow this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228201897) you will see that they tell you that in order to support deep link properly, every item that is accessible from the bottom navigation needs to be a nested graph.

> So what you need to do is make sure that each navigation destination used in your bottom navigation view is a  element - that's the clue to Navigation that it needs to swap back stacks when handling your deep link

I did that and it works perfectly.
Just a heads up, I use something like this to do the navigation:

```
navController.navigate(route, navOptions {
            launchSingleTop = true  
            restoreState = true
            popUpTo("your start destination") {
                inclusive = false
                saveState = true
            }
})
```

This means I support multiple backstacks.

Here it is important to notice "your home destination" which has to be the start destination of you home nested graph. If you use

```
navController.graph.startDestinationRoute
```

Then you will receive an exception that says the destination can not be found. In that case startDestinationRoute will point to the nested graph, which surprise me that the library can not pick it up and translate it to the startDestination of the home nested graph.

Comment: While it solved the case with the first destination this behavior now shows up for every screen you minimize an app on that isn't a deep link destination. It happens only with a running app where you handle deep link manually.

Comment: @user128440 resolved, just needed to pass same navOptions as in the answer of Leandro Ocampo to the navigate method of the NavController alongside with a deep link.